# Help with quick UML confusion

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation, class-diagram

I want to know what it would be if I had a Ticket that holds one TicketType but a ticket type can be part of many Tickets.

Would the relationship be an Aggregation, where the open diamond is at the Ticket class, or is it an association where the arrow is pointing to the TicketType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was "Who cares?"  You're trying to express a relationship between two objects for yourself or other developers.  You can't even articulate the difference; what are the chances that others will be able to do it?

The association with open diamond says the Ticket owns a TicketType, but the type isn't deleted if the Ticket goes away.

I'm not sure what additional information this provides over and above the simple arrow for association.

I think it's important not to be too hung up on these things.  Don't get too carried away with UML.

Comment: OK thanks, it does make sense, that if a Ticket is deleted the Ticket Types are still there which should be.

Comment: +1 @duffymo.  The UML aggregation association causes more confusion than its worth.  The important questions are cardinality (must there be at least one? Can there be more than one?) and the delete behaviour.  My advice would always be to answer those questions first - and stick with a simple binary association.  Aggregation only has one useful property, and that only occurs in recursive aggregates.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sfinnie.  I think my answer is quite adequate as it stands.  Maybe you're confused about aggregation; I'm not.  You're certainly free to offer your own.

Comment: My intention was to agree with you, not offer you advice.  Hence +1.  Advice - if there was any - was for OP.  Namely, don't get hung up on aggregation.  Concentrate on the two questions that matter (cardinality + delete behaviour).